# How do you encapsulate vinyl asbestos tiles and black mastic in a home basement?

Tags: basement, asbestos

My basement contains VAT and black mastic (where missing tiles used to be). I want to encapsulate the tiles and mastic and install a floating floor. Do I need to use a self-leveling product over the black mastic? What product can be used to seal the tiles? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would fill any voids where there are missing tiles. If you want to paint the tiles that encapsulates it but the underlayment foam for the floating floor will be enough to do the same. If you do not use a underlayment foam the flooring will wear through paint and even some less expensive epoxy paints so a quality underlayment helps in the long run to decouple cold, moisture from the slab.